# android:how to call method from hyperlink

Tags: android

I am trying to click a hyperlink and call method in android programming...

But the problem is , the link is not showing up and neither the method is getting called. How to achieve this result?

I am basically a javascript/jsp developer, this is my first android application , which i am learning. Accordingly i am trying to click link and call method with parameter....

[image]

Results looking like  [image]

**Java code**

```
private class CallAPI extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private String Content;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
      String urlString=params[0]; // URL to call
      String resultToDisplay = "";
      InputStream in = null;
      emailVerificationResult result = null;

      // HTTP Get
      try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("test");
          BufferedReader reader = null;
          // Get the server response
          reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
          StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
          String line = null;
          // Read Server Response
          while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
              // Append server response in string
              sb.append(line + "\n");
          }
          // Append Server Response To Content String
          Content = sb.toString();
      } catch (Exception e ) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        return e.getMessage();
      }
        /****************** Start Parse Response JSON Data *************/
        String OutputData = "<center><b><u>Weight Training</u></b></center><br/><br/>";
        JSONObject jsonResponse;
        try {
            /****** Creates a new JSONObject with name/value mappings from the JSON string. ********/
            jsonResponse = new JSONObject(Content);
            /***** Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is a JSONArray. ***/
            /*******  Returns null otherwise.  *******/
            JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("articleList");
            /*********** Process each JSON Node ************/
            int lengthJsonArr = jsonMainNode.length();
            for (int i = 0; i < lengthJsonArr; i++) {
                /****** Get Object for each JSON node.***********/
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                /******* Fetch node values **********/
                String name = jsonChildNode.optString("menu_name").toString();
                String number = jsonChildNode.optString("id").toString();
                String date_added = jsonChildNode.optString("parent_id").toString();

                OutputData += "  " +
                        String.format("<a  onClick='verifyEmail("+number+","+date_added+")'><b>"+name+"<b> "+ number+" "+ date_added+"</a> ") +"<br/><br/>";
            }
            /****************** End Parse Response JSON Data *************/ 
            /* Show Parsed Output on screen (activity) */
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        resultToDisplay =OutputData ;
       return resultToDisplay;

    }
    // This is the method that is called when the submit button is clicked
    public void verifyEmail(String m,String p) {
        String urlString = apiURL + "mid=" + m + "&pid=" + p;
        new CallAPI().execute(urlString);
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ResultActivity.class); 
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, result);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

**`Update:`**
Instead of link, can i put a button and provide on click method and pass parameter to the method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Thankfully) You cannot call a function using HTML tags in android. Instead try setting [ClickableSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ClickableSpan.html) on you you TextView to get the desired effect

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Click Me to do magic");
ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View textView) {
        doSomeMagic();
    }
    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        super.updateDrawState(ds);
    }
};

// apply the clickable span on "Click Me" part which is on index 0 -> 7
// 8 is used because it goes from a -> b-1
ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, 0, 8, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.foo);
textView.setText(ss);
```

Comment: Thanks Sourabh, But Sorry,i did not get how to achieve this http://i.stack.imgur.com/9hOtt.png

Comment: When you are creating your list, and when setting text in textview, inside ClickableSpan's on click call the method with the parameters.

Comment: I have diffrent method for setview in diffrent class, what i am doing is first getting list from one class and setting those list in text view from another class.  Instead of links can i put button and passparameter onclick of button if its easy then this

Comment: I didn't really understood what you said but you'd have to attach an onClick listener to a button anyway, which is similar to using ClickableSpan